# SQL Update - Adding to String to One Attribute

Tags: mysql

My mysql table is : Product (name,price,metaDescription)

I want to write an SQL UPDATE to Set my metaDescription name+' is only just for'+metaDescription

I tried this but it didn't work

```
UPDATE 
  product 
SET 
  metaDescription=name+' is just for'+price;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`concat` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
update product
set metaDescription = concat(name, ' is just for ', price);
```

MySQL should automatically convert `price` to a string type for you.

MySQL is trying to convert your strings to numbers (and silently failing) when you use `+`:

```
mysql> select 'this' + 'that';
+-----------------+
| 'this' + 'that' |
+-----------------+
|               0 |
+-----------------+
```